# Building Array of elements sorted by priorities of each(defined inside objects in an arraylist)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections

I have a list of type `List<Element<Integer, Integer>>`, where each element contains two integers, one the entityId & another the priority for that entity. Now I need to create an array `Integer[]` of entityIds that has been sorted according to the priorities put for each entity within the `Element` object.

I have access to, only the iterator of the list. What is the best way to create such priority sorted array of entityIds  ?

---

## My idea:

Using the iterator to first create an array of elements, sorting them using the priorities using `Arrays.sort()`& then creating a new array of Integers & copying the entityIds from that sorted array. Is this a good idea ? Or are there any better alternatives than this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your list into a PriorityQueue with a Comparator that looks at the priorities; then iterate over the priority queue and collect the array.

Untested code follows; please feel free to fix typos.

```
Integer[] getSortedEntityIds(Iterator<Element<Integer, Integer>> iter) {
  Comparator<Element<Integer,Integer>> comp = new Comparator<Element<Integer, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Element<Integer,Integer> ela, Element<Integer,Integer> elb) {
      return ela.getPriority().compareTo(elb.getPriority());
    }
  };

  PriorityQueue<Element<Integer,Integer>>pq = new PriorityQueue<Element<Integer,Integer>>(256, comp);
  // If you had the access to the whole list, you wouldn't have to iterate, you could just pass it into the pq constructor
  while(iter.hasNext() {
    pq.add(iter.next());
  }

  Integer[] sortedEntityIds = new Integer[pq.size()]

  for(int i = 0; i < pq.size(), i++) {
    Element<Integer, Integer>el = pq.remove();
    sortedEntityIds[i] = el.getEntityId();
  }

  return sortedEntityIds;
}
```

Comment: What about just putting it in an array & using Arrays.sort() instead ?

Comment: Well, you can't put them into an array unless you know the size of the original list (you said you only have an iterator). You can add them into a List and then sort it; I think that's pretty equivalent to adding them to a PriorityQueue...

Comment: Ok. well, I don't see anything with using sort(). In terms of algorithmic complexity, it's equivalent in theory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Equivalence_of_priority_queues_and_sorting_algorithms . But I'm not sure if PriorityQueue has a significant memory overhead. Bottom line is, I think sorted array is a fine implementation, especially if it's more natural for you as far as code maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create second list.
2. Get next item from original list.
3. Iterate through second list and find first item with greater priority.
4. Insert current item before it.
5. Goto 2 or end.

Comment: my lists are large sized(16000) & thus I cannot afford selection sort with n^2 complexity

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom comparator to sort the list elements in any way you see fit.

```
final List<Element<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Element<Integer, Integer>>();
list.add(new Element<Integer, Integer>(1, 1));
list.add(new Element<Integer, Integer>(4, 4));
list.add(new Element<Integer, Integer>(3, 3));
list.add(new Element<Integer, Integer>(2, 2));
list.add(new Element<Integer, Integer>(5, 5));

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Element<Integer, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(final Element<Integer, Integer> x,
            final Element<Integer, Integer> y) {
        return x.getPriority().compareTo(y.getPriority());
    }
});

// Prints elements in ascending order of priority
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```